# Partition Disks on VirtualBox When installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: installation, server, virtualbox, partitioning

Which option should I select in the 'Partition disks' screen when installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64 on an Oracle VirtualBox?

Options are:

```
Guided - resize SCSI3 (0,0,0), partition #5 (sda) and use freed space  
Guided - use entire disk   
Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM   
Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM  
Manual
```

I selected Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM but then got this scary message: `Note that all data on the disk you select will be erased, but not before you have confirmed that you really want to make the changes.`

I'm assuming it's only referring to the virtual hard drive and not the real hard drive on my computer. Just want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,its just refferring your virtual hard drive and not the real hard-drive.It doesn't affect your main hard-drive,i'm sure about that.